# CSS attribute 'contain' not working

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to display the entirety of an image within a `div`.

I'm having difficulty displaying an image with the `background-size` property set to `contain` - it does not display the whole image, only the centre, at the full size of the source image.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yohLs3es/)

**Code**

```css
#header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#header .logo {
    width: calc(100%/3);
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: contain;
    background: url(http://startupweekend.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/CokeLogo1.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, try to avoid using calc for a simple calculation like this, just write `33.333%` instead. That's precise enough and works in Android 4.3 and below as well.

Comment: On the subject of the `calc`, for better cross browser compatibility, operators should be surrounded by spaces, like so: `calc(100% / 3)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you overwrite the first property, you must move `background-size` property after `background`, like so:

```
#header .logo {
    background: url(http://startupweekend.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/CokeLogo1.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

> This is because the shorthand background property will overwrite all preceding background-* properties whether they're included in the shorthand or not.

***Shaggy** comment*

Comment: Thank you, it works - the size isn't being set in the `background` property, so why does `background-size` need to be stated afterward?

Comment: This is because the shorthand `background` property will overwrite all preceding `background-*` properties whether they're included in the shorthand or not.

Comment: Because background is shortcut for many background properties. Background shortcut overwrite all background properties previously defined.

Comment: @Bluety Include the reason why into your answer and you have a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Styles will be applied from top to bottom, hence style `background-size:contain;` is overwritten by position described in `background: url(http://startupweekend.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/CokeLogo1.png) no-repeat center center;`

You need to add `background-size:contain;` below the `background:`. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yohLs3es/1/)

```css
#header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
#header .logo {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(http://startupweekend.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/CokeLogo1.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should edit this to clarify that it doesn't need to be at the end of the rule, simply after the `background` property.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `background-size:contain;` after background

```
#header {
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
color:#ccc;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
z-index:3;
padding:20px 0;
}
#header .logo {
width: calc(100%/3);
height:75px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: url(http://startupweekend.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/CokeLogo1.png) no-repeat center center;
background-size:contain;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the Background Size using ‘contain’ or ‘cover’
The two other possible values for background size are the keywords contain and cover.
If the contain keyword is used, the background image is scaled, while preserving the image’s original proportions / aspect ratio, so as to be as large as possible providing that it is contained within the background positioning area, ie. neither the image’s width or height exceed the background positioning area. As such, depending on whether or not the proportions of the background image match those of the background positioning area, there may be some areas of the background which are not covered by the background image.
If the cover keyword is the used, the background image is scaled, again preserving the image’s original proportions / aspect ratio, this time to be as large as possible so that the background positioning area is completely covered by the background image, ie. both the images width or height are equal to or exceed the background positioning area. As such, again depending on whether or not the proportions of the background image match those of the background positioning area, some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area.

```css
#header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
#header .logo {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(http://startupweekend.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/CokeLogo1.png) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
          background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change positions background-size and background.

Write something like this:

```
background: url(http://startupweekend.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/CokeLogo1.png) no-repeat center center;
background-size: contain;
```

It's because `background` property overwrites `background-size` :)